# How can I update my local SQLite database whenever there is any update in my Contacts

Tags: android, sqlite, contentobserver

I am creating an Android application where I have a local SQLite data base to store the user details selected from the contact list. I wish to update my SQLite database whenever there is any update in my phone Contacts. I made use of Content Observer but as I am new to Android development could anyone help me in the usage of ContentObserver and the methods I can follow in order to update my local database.

Comment: you can use service to check periodically if there is change in contact and update you data base..

Answer (score 2):

ContentObserver is an abstract class with no abstract methods. Its two onChange() methods are implemented without any logic. And since these are called whenever a change occurs, you have to override them.

Since Google added one of the two overloaded onChange() methods as recently as API-level 16, this method’s default behavior is to call the other, older method.

Here is, what a normal implementation would look like:

```
class MyObserver extends ContentObserver {
 public MyObserver(Handler handler) {
  super(handler);
}

 @Override
 public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
  this.onChange(selfChange, null);
 }      

  @Override
  public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
  // do s.th.
  // depending on the handler you might be on the UI
  // thread, so be cautious!
 }
}
```

Some things are important with the above code. The first thing you must know, is that the second method is only available from API level 16 onwards. That’s why I added the SuppressLint annotation. The code works fine on older devices, but in this case Android obviously always calls the old one. So your code should not rely on a URI to work properly.

Also notice the Handler parameter in the constructor. This handler is used to deliver the onChange() method. So if you created the Handler on the UI thread, the onChange() method will be called on the UI thread as well. In this case avoid querying the ContentProvider in this method. Instead use an AsyncTask or a Loader.

If you pass a null value to the constructor, Android calls the onChange() method immediately – regardless of the current thread used. I think it’s best to always use a handler when creating the ContentObserver object.

Register your content observer to listen for changes

To register your ContentObserver subclass you simply have to call the ContentResolver's registerContentObserver() method:

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(SOME_URI,true,yourObserver);
```

It takes three parameters. The first is the URI to listen to. I cover the URI in more detail in the next section.

The second parameter indicates whether all changes to URIs that start with the given URI should trigger a method call or just changes to exactly this one URI. This can be handy for say the ContactsContract URI with its many descendants. But it can also be detrimental in that the actual change, that caused the method call, is even more obscure to you.

The third parameter is an instance of your ContentObserver implementation.

The URIs you can observe

As described in my introduction to content providers content URIs can be directory-based or id-based.

Both of these URI-types can be used for your content observer. If you have a detail screen you would use an id-based URI for your observer, and when you use a list of data a directory-based URI is more appropriate.

This does not always work, though. ContactsContract for example always triggers a change, whenever any contact was changed, even if you are listening to a more specific URI. It depends on the correct implementation of the content provider. I have filed a bug report for the ContactsContract provider. Please vote for this issue, if you agree.

When you write a content provider for your app, take care of notifying the correct URI. Only if you do so, the feedback mechanism described here works. This is important for your observers – or if the provider is exported for your clients’ observers as well. And it is also important for Loaders. See my post about how to write content providers to learn more about this.

Note: If you use Loaders you do not need to listen to changes yourself. In this case Android registers a ContentObserver and triggers your LoaderCallbacks onLoadFinished() method for any changes.

Do not forget to unregister your content observer

When you have registered a content observer, it is your responsibility to also unregister it. Otherwise you would create a memory leak and your Activity would never be garbage collected.

To unregister you call the unregisterContentObserver() method of the ContentResolver:

```
getContentResolver().
  unregisterContentObserver(yourObserver);
```